# Undefined property: Illuminate\Pagination\LengthAwarePaginator::$event_parts

Tags: php, eloquent, laravel-8

I received this error while trying to run two-layer loops in order to get a list out of an array:

> Undefined property: Illuminate\Pagination\LengthAwarePaginator::$event_parts

I wanted to produce a table where it lists all my events and at the same time there is a column that listed all the attending participants.

Here is the phpmyadmin table:
[image]

Here is my EventController:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Models\Event;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class EventController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        $events = Event::paginate(5);

        return view('events.index', compact('events'))
            ->with('i', (request()->input('page', 1) - 1) * 5);

    }

    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function create()
    {
        $events = Event::all();

        return view('events.create', compact('events'));


        ##return view('events.create');

    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $request->validate([
            'event_name' => 'required',
            'event_start' => 'required',
            'event_end' => 'required',
            'event_category' => 'required',
            #'event_part' => 'required'
        ]);

        Event::create($request->all());

       return redirect()->route('events.index')
          ->with('success', 'Event added successfully.');
    }

    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  \App\Models\Event  $event
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function show(Event $event)
    {
        return view('events.show', compact('event'));
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  \App\Models\Event  $event
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function edit(Event $event)
    {
        return view('events.edit', compact('event'));
    }

    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \App\Models\Event  $event
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function update(Request $request, Event $event)
    {
        $request->validate([
            'event_name' => 'required',
            'event_start' => 'required',
            'event_end' => 'required',
            'event_category' => 'required'
        ]);

        $event->update($request->all());

        return redirect()->route('events.index')
            ->with('success', 'Event updated successfully');
    }

    /**
     * Remove the specified resource from storage.
     *
     * @param  \App\Models\Event  $event
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function destroy(Event $event)
    {
        $event->delete();

        return redirect()->route('events.index')
            ->with('success', 'Event deleted successfully');
    }
}
```

Here is my migration:

```
    <?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

class CreateEventsTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('events', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id('event_id');
            $table->string('event_name');
            $table->datetime('event_start');
            $table->datetime('event_end');
            $table->string('event_category');
            $table->json('event_parts')->nullable();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('events');
    }
}
```

Here is my index.blade.php:

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12 margin-tb">
            <div class="pull-left">
                <h2>Laravel 8 CRUD </h2>
            </div>
            <div class="pull-right">
                <a class="btn btn-success" href="{{ route('events.create') }}" title="Create a event"> <i class="fas fa-plus-circle"></i>
                    </a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    @if ($message = Session::get('success'))
        <div class="alert alert-success">
            <p>{{ $message }}</p>
        </div>
    @endif

    <table class="table table-bordered table-responsive-lg">
        <tr>
            <th>No</th>
            <th>Event Name</th>
            <th>Event Start</th>
            <th>Event End</th>
            <th>Event Category</th>
            <th>Event Participants</th>
            <th width="280px">Action</th>
        </tr>
        @foreach ($events as $event )
            <tr>
                <td>{{ ++$i }}</td>
                <td>{{ $event->event_name }}</td>
                <td>{{ $event->event_start }}</td>
                <td>{{ $event->event_end }}</td>
                <td>{{ $event->event_category }}</td>
                <td> @foreach ($events->event_parts as $event_part) {{ $event_part }} @endforeach</td>

                <td>
                    <form action="{{ route('events.destroy', $event->event_id) }}" method="POST">

                        <a href="{{ route('events.show', $event->event_id) }}" title="show">
                            <i class="fas fa-eye text-success  fa-lg">View</i>
                        </a>

                        <a href="{{ route('events.edit', $event->event_id) }}">
                            <i class="fas fa-edit  fa-lg">Edit</i>

                        </a>

                        @csrf
                        @method('DELETE')

                        <button type="submit" title="delete" style="border: none; background-color:transparent;">
                            <i class="fas fa-trash fa-lg text-danger">Delete</i>

                        </button>
                    </form>
                </td>
            </tr>
        @endforeach
    </table>

    {!! $events->links() !!}

@endsection
```

Comment: `@foreach ($events->event_parts as $event_part)` Shouldn't that be `@foreach ($event->event_parts as $event_part)`? You're doing a nested `@foreach()`, but you're trying to access `event_parts` from `$events` instead of `$event`. You could also simply do `<td>{{ $event->event_parts->implode(' ') }}</td>` instead; the extra `@foreach` seems pointless.

Comment: `<td>{{ collect($event->event_parts)->implode() }}</td>` would be more accurate; array vs Collection.

Comment: Tried the first one & received this error: "Invalid argument supplied for foreach() (View:"

The second solution led to this error: "Too few arguments to function Illuminate\Support\Collection::implode(), 0 passed in"

Comment: What does `$event->event_parts` contain? Is it a relationship? A string? An array? And sorry, `implode(' ')` (empty/blank space)

Comment: It is a select option from the values of $event->event_name and it forms array from that values (as per my MySQL table image above).

Comment: Right, but if it's a string, you can't do a `foreach()` on it without `explode()`ing it into an array first. You may have converted it in a different part of your code, etc etc. Having a comma separated list in a single column of a database is generally considered bad design/anti-pattern, as this should be a proper relational entity (`event`, `parts`, `event_parts`, or a `parts` table with an `event_id`, etc etc)

Comment: I see. Thank you Tim for your help. So by any chance, how do we usually store database from a select option? I wanted the event list to show those who are attending and these attendees are also registered users (from a different table 'users').

Comment: No problem! Your select should have `<option value="{{ $user->id }}">{{ $user->name }}</option>` (for example, but each option should have a value and label, ID and name generally). Then, using Laravel's Eloquent Model/Relationship, you should have 3 tables, `event`, `user` and `event_user`, and 2 Models, `Event.php` and `User.php`, and 2 relationships `public function users() { return $this->belongsToMany(User::class)` and `public function events() { return $this->belongsToMany(Event::class)`. Then, on submit, link em via `$event->users()->sync($request->input('users'))`.

Comment: It's a bit of a broad comment, and not the main purpose of this question, since you have a simple syntax error, but you can read everything on a `many-to-many` relationship here: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many